Add custom post type fields to DIVI without a Child Theme
My question is similar to How to show custom fields in divi blog module? The difference is that I'm looking for a way to do it without a child theme or editing DIVI php files. Perhaps via a plugin that can insert the code in specific files or other means.
Theme: DIVI
Plugin for UI/Custom Postype fields: Advance Custom Fields (ACF)
The plugin code snippet, can add code without affecting the files and even turn snippets on/off but only inserts code to functions.php
According to Elegant Theme's documentation the code needs to be in blog.php
A workaround for code snippets plugin would be a snippet that will work on functions.php!
Is there's a plugin/snippet that can force custom fields into DIVI, or other means without the need for a child theme?

You can enable the Divi builder on blog posts. From there you can display any content from custom fields. No need for additional plug-ins.

blog posts is very limited. Only allows you to use standard fields like title, featured image, etc. It does not let you add custom fields. I have ACF and it won't add them to the blog post module
